# Cross validation in deep neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, cross-validation

How do you perform cross-validation in a deep neural network? I know that to perform cross validation to will train it on all folds except one and test it on the excluded fold. Then do this for k fold times and average the accuries for each fold. How do you do this for each iteration. Do you update the parameters at each fold? Or you perform k-fold cross validation for each iteration? Or is each training on all folds but one fold considered as one iteration?

Comment: You do K-Fold Cross Validation the same way as any other ML model, you just train K models. This has nothing to do with iterations.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Because we update the parameters every iteration right? So is doing cross validation considered as one iteration?

Comment: No , updating parameters has nothing to do with cross validation!

Comment: Hmm what is it good for then?

Comment: To get a less biased view of model performance, you might train a model in a train/test split and get good performance  just because of chance, so how does model performance change when you vary the training data? That's the question K-Fold CV is supposed to answer.

Comment: So cross validation is done outside training?

Answer (score 4):

**Stratified cross validation**
There are a couple of solution available to run deep neural network in fold-cross validation.

```
def create_baseline():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
# evaluate model with standardized dataset
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, epochs=100, batch_size=5,     verbose=0)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, encoded_Y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is a general technique in ML to prevent overfitting. There is no difference between doing it on a deep-learning model and doing it on a linear regression. The idea is the same for all ML models. The basic idea behind CV, you described in your question is correct.

But the question *how do you do this for each iteration* does not make sense. There is nothing in CV algorithm that relates to iterations while training. You trained your model and only then you evaluate it.

*Do you update the parameters at each fold?*. You train the same model k-times and most probably each time you will have different parameters.

---

The answer that CV is not needed in DL is wrong. The basic idea of CV is to have a better estimate of how your model is performing on a limited dataset. So if your dataset is small the ability to train k models will give you a better estimate (the downsize is that you spend ~k times more time). If you have 100mln examples, most probably having 5% testing/validation set will already give you a good estimate.

Comment: Is 44k samples sufficient? And what I meant was, an iteration means updating the parameter. So if at each fold you update the parameter then wouldn't that be considered as an iteration?

Comment: @Chaine *Is 44k samples sufficient?* no one except of you can answer this question.

Comment: What I meant was if it's sufficient for using holdout instead of cross validation